# Set Notificiation in Selected time, date with edittext variables in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have datepicker,timepicker , edittext variables on my project . I can select date and time and I can set notification but ıt's work only selected time  and for example ı set a lot notificition for future It can works only some parts and they works wrong edittext varibles . How can ı set notification more then one with my edittext varibles on selected time and date . It's important . I will solve my problem in 5 day . Can you be fast . Please

**Main Activity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    Button hatirlaticitarihsaat,backhome,restore;
    EditText editisim,editaciklama;
    ImageView tickx;
    TextView textbasariylakuruldu,texthatirlaticibas,hatirlaticiaciktext,tarih;
    TimePickerDialog tpd;
    DatePickerDialog dpd;
    private int notificationId = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hatirlatici);
        tarih=findViewById(R.id.tarihzaman);
 tickx=findViewById(R.id.tick);
        editisim=findViewById(R.id.hatbaslik);
        textbasariylakuruldu=findViewById(R.id.textbasariylakuruldu);
        texthatirlaticibas=findViewById(R.id.texthatirlaticibas);
        hatirlaticiaciktext=findViewById(R.id.hatirlaticiaciktext);
        editaciklama=findViewById(R.id.hataciklama);
        hatirlaticitarihsaat= findViewById(R.id.taarihsaatbutton);
        hatirlaticitarihsaat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
                datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date picker");
            }
        });


    }
 
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hourOfDay, int minute) {


        now.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        now.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        now.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        String isim = editisim.getText().toString();
String aciklamax = editaciklama.getText().toString();
Calendar startalarm = Calendar.getInstance();
        startalarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        startalarm.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        startalarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        startNotification(now);

    }

    private void startNotification(Calendar now){
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.setAction("ALERT_RECIEVER");
        intent.putExtra("notificationId", notificationId);
        intent.putExtra("titlex", editisim.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("messagex", editaciklama.getText().toString());
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,1,intent,0);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, now.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    }


    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {

        DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
        timePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "time picker");
now.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day );
        now.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        now.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
 Intent intent = new Intent(hatirlatici.this, AlertReciever.class);
        PendingIntent alarmintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                hatirlatici.this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
        );

    }

}
```

***DatePickerFragment.java***

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getActivity(),year ,month,day);


    }
}
```

***TimePickerFragment.java***

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), (TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener) getActivity(), hour,minute, android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }
}
```

***AlertReciever.java***

```
public class AlertReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private Notification notification;
    private static final String ChannelID = "Sample_Channel";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int NotificationId = intent.getIntExtra("notificationId", 0);
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("messagex");
        String title = intent.getStringExtra("titlex");
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(context, hatirlatici.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context,0,mainIntent,0
        );
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            CharSequence channelName = "My Notification";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(ChannelID,channelName,importance);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, ChannelID)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_menu_book_24);

        notificationManager.notify(NotificationId, builder.build());
    }


}
```

Comment: ` they works wrong edittext variables` . Can you explain the situation? I'm not quite understand

Comment: For Example my 3. Notification is work with 2.Notifications variables

Comment: And When I set a lot of Notification for future works only some part

Comment: Did you mean, you set the alarm after 2 mins, and then you set again for another 2 mins ?

Comment: No I set the alarm after 5 mins and then set again after 10 minutes and set again 15 minutes

Comment: It is suppose there is no problem about that. So what happened ?

Comment: Sometimes It didnt push notification and sometimes the notifications text is can be mix last or next notifications edittext variables